# Multiple Carousel Pagination sync issue inside Infinite FlatList

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-snap-carousel

Reactive Native Expo Mobile App: I am using [React Native Snap Carousel using this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-native-to-implement-a-carousel/) to pop out the images from my database.

I have an infinite flat list with individual entries as React Native Snap Carousels, thus having multiple carousels with multiple Paginations.

On having multiple carousels, the Pagination index now is moving commonly as the same index and carousel ref is being used by all Paginations.

Please let me know how to map the carousel ref and pagination indexes such that the multiple carousels in my FlatList works fine.

Code I am using, for Reference:

```
const isCarousel = React.useRef(null);
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

const renderItem = ({item}) => {
return(
                // Some Card Stuff...
                <Carousel
                layout="tinder"
                layoutCardOffset={9}
                ref={isCarousel}
                data={photoArray}
                renderItem={CarouselCardItem}
                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
                itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
                inactiveSlideShift={0}
                onSnapToItem={(index) => setIndex(index)}
                useScrollView={true}
              />
              <Pagination
                      dotsLength={photoArray.length}
                      activeDotIndex={index}
                      carouselRef={isCarousel}
                      dotStyle={{
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        marginHorizontal: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92)'
                      }}
                      inactiveDotStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(4, 5, 3, 0.92)'
                      }}
                      inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
                      inactiveDotScale={0.6}
                      tappableDots={true}
                    />
// Some more Stuff....
)
```

And the main FlatList:

```
return (
        <FlatList 
        data={data_data} 
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor = {item => `${item.identifier}`}
        ListFooterComponent = {Loader}
        onEndReached = {loadStuff}
        onRefresh = {() => refreshData()}
        refreshing = {isRefreshing}
/>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Custom Carousel component by using your code like

```
const MyCarousel =({item}) => {
   const isCarousel = React.useRef(null);
   const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
   
   return (
     <React.Fragment>
     <Carousel
        layout="tinder"
        layoutCardOffset={9}
        ref={isCarousel}
        data={photoArray}
        renderItem={CarouselCardItem}
        sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
        itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
        inactiveSlideShift={0}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => setIndex(index)}
        useScrollView={true}/>
        <Pagination
          dotsLength={photoArray.length}
          activeDotIndex={index}
          carouselRef={isCarousel}
          dotStyle={{
           width: 10,
           height: 10,
           borderRadius: 5,
           marginHorizontal: 0,
           backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92)'
          }}
          inactiveDotStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(4, 5, 3, 0.92)' }}
          inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
          inactiveDotScale={0.6}
          tappableDots={true}/>
    </React.Fragment>
   )
}
```

Then Use it like below

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
   return(
    <View>
     <MyCarousel item={item}/> 
     // Some more Stuff....
    </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: I am trying this but the <Pagination line is not getting recognized now as a JS code.... It showing a runtime syntax error saying:  Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

Comment: The above error is resolved by wrapping carousel code under React.Fragment.... Please accept the edit and I can mark this as answer.

Comment: There is only one problem in this method though. Whenever the Flatlist is reloading on end reached, to get more content then  All the carousels and paginations are getting reset to first photo/index.

Comment: Because when you update state (list) the screen will repaint.

Comment: Resolved the above by segregating the other card parts into their own components. Now i need to embed YouTube video in the card as well, which I am finding difficult to do....